# How can I include a macro on a confluence page from the jenkins confluence plugin?

Tags: git, macros, jenkins-plugins, confluence

I`m using the confluence plugin in Jenkins (ver. 1.642.4) to publish build results to Confluence (6.0.7)

I`m using the jenkins plugin "Confluence Publisher 1.8".

a script in the Jenkins build job parses some Git branches for certain types of comments. From that log, it creates a text file (CHANGELOG-jenkins.md) which is published to Confluence.

in order to display the text in a friendly way, I`m using the Confluence Markdown macro. [result for the page I create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKt5i.png)
I add the macro, and add a token text {jenkins-marker:Release_Notes_Generator_Confluence}.
The jenkins plugin for confluence can then write inside the Markdown Macro and the text is rendered correctly.

However, I need jenkins to create a new confluence page (per build) and so I need a way to automate the macro insertion and Tag

The jenkins plugin already creates a page if it doesn't exist. So I need to be able to add the markdown macro to the new page after it`s been created. I also then need to add the token text to the macro.

so far I have not been able to find any way to do this. it seems that macros "have" to be inserted by hand

https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf53/working-with-macros-411108564.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I ended up in finding an alternative (and probably better solution in the long run)

I'm using confluence's REST API to add the markdown macro to the page.
I wasn`t able to find any doc on JSON needed to add it, but luckily, it`s quite a simple macro, so it wasn't too difficult to discover the required fields. This is the minimum required.

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"markdown\">
    <ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[<b>This is my code</b>]]></ac:plain-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

the request URL and body

```
https://<confluence_url>:443/rest/api/content/12944217


{
    "id": "12944217",
    "type": "page",
    "status": "current",
    "title": "Release Notes From Jenkins",
    "space": {
        "key": "THEKEY",
        "metadata": {}
    },
        "version": {
        "number": 51,
        "minorEdit": false,
        "hidden": false
    },
    "ancestors": [],
    "operations": [],
    "body": {
        "storage": {
            "value":"<p></ac:structured-macro></p><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"markdown\"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[<b>jenkins-marker:Release_Notes_Generator_Confluence</b>]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro></p>",
        "representation": "storage"
        }
},
"metadata": {}
```

}